# Return coordinates of text object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf-controls, system.drawing

I am using System.drawing to place text onto an object that is later used as a template to create a business card for a user.  My problem is that the coordinates of the text placed is different depending on the resolution and size of the monitor that is being used.

Is there a way to create a static container that will remain the exact same size no matter what screen it is viewed on?  Kind of like a drawing canvas.